# How to use XPath to select following-sibling

Tags: xpath

```
<tr>
                        <td width="120" align="right" class="tit">application：</td>
                        <td style="width:345px;word-break:break-all;">




                                <a  style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0066ff; cursor: pointer"
                                        href="javascript:_search('pa',  '<font color=red>PartA</font>PartB');"> <font color=red>PartA</font>PartB</a>;



                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
```

In above code, I use part of the name (Part A) to search result, how can I get the whole name which combines PartA and PartB. I use below code and just get PartA and nothing

```
html.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"application")]/following-sibling::td[1]/a/font/text()')[0]
html.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"application")]/following-sibling::td[1]/a/text()')[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your second XPath accordingly :

```
//td[contains(text(),"application")]/following-sibling::td[1]/a/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Output : `Part B`

To select the two items directly you can use :

```
//td[contains(text(),"application")]/following-sibling::td[1]//text()[normalize-space()]
```

To combine them :

```
concat(//td[contains(text(),"application")]/following-sibling::td[1]/a/font/text(),//td[contains(text(),"application")]/following-sibling::td[1]/a/text()[normalize-space()])
```

or

```
string(//td[contains(text(),"application")]/following-sibling::td[1]/a)
```

Output : `PartAPartB`